# Meaning of polynomially larger, / smaller and meaning of polynomial larger / polynomial smaller

Tags: recurrence-relation

Hi I have spent the last two hours trying to find a general definition for both of these terms, but it seems like in computer science, people do not really agree on definitions. And I haven't even been able to find it in my slides my lecture notes or in the current book I am using.

Could anyone please give me some general definitions for these terms with some concrete examples? And if you are able to give me some general definitions could you cite where you got it from?

Comment: "I haven't even been able to find it in the current book I am using". Please edit the question to add a reference to the book you are using. As a general rule, whenever there might be disagreement, you are supposed to identify the exact situation you are in. General situations can be described later.

Comment: That does not answer my question at all

Comment: I agreed and agree that my previous **comment** did not answer your question at all. What I asked you to do is to clarify your question so that an answer could be written to the point. Please add a reference to the book you are using. It should help people post more better answers faster.

Comment: Reference, reference and reference. Reference is too important to miss. "if you are able to give me some general definitions could you cite where you got it from?" Since you are asking references be included in the answer, is it reasonable for you to provide some reference in the question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614848/meaning-of-polynomially-larger